# Initialization of static class member raises "does not name a type" error

Tags: c++, templates

Compiling the following code with `g++` outputs the following error:

```
main.cpp:51:19: error: 'running_id' in 'class MyContainer<int>' does not name a type
   51 | MyContainer<int>::running_id = 0;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:11:16: note: 'MyContainer<int>::running_id' declared here
   11 |     static int running_id;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
// #include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
    public:
    static int running_id;

    MyContainer() {
        cout << "Allocating" << endl;
        array = new T[8];
        id = running_id++;
    }

    T& operator[](int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    ~MyContainer() {
        if (array) {
            cout << "Deallocating" << endl;
            delete[] array;
        }
    }

    MyContainer(const MyContainer& other) {
        cout << "Copy ctor" << endl;
        std::copy(other.array, other.array + 8, array);
    }

    MyContainer& operator=(const MyContainer& other) {
        cout << "operator=" << endl;
        if (this == &other) {
            return *this;
        }
        std::copy(other.array, other.array + 8, array);
        return *this;
    }

    int id{0};

    private:
    T* array = nullptr;
};

MyContainer<int>::running_id = 0;
```

I have read here on SO that `running_id` should be declared before it is used. But it doesn't seem to be the problem here, since `MyContainer` is declared before the line which causes the error.

As an additional question: is there a way to not have to do `MyContainer<T>::running_id = 0;` for every possible `T`? The compiler complains if I leave the template argument out.

Comment: You forgot the type specifier int. int MyContainer<int>::running_id = 0;

Comment: Note that having this (corrected) line in a header file would lead to ODR violation,  this problem can be avoided by  following Paul Sanders' advice

Comment: @M.M Just deleted my previous comment because I think I understand: before `inline` variables were introduces in C++ 17, did we simply use to define static member variables in the matching `.cpp` source (instead of the header)?

Comment: @AvivCohn yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the static member like this:

```
template <typename T>
int MyContainer<T>::running_id = 0;
```

now this will work automatically for every `T` as you want.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 and later, you can declare your class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
public:
    static inline int running_id = 0;
    ...
```

You then don't need the (faulty) `MyContainer<int>::running_id = 0;` line.